# Does babel portuguese obey the new ortography rules (Novo Acordo Ortográfico)?

Tags: babel

I just noticed that,  when I use babel Portuguese, a rule like `\today` produces something like `13 de Março de 2019`. But this is wrong in regards to the new orthography of Portuguese (Novo Acordo Ortográfico), because name of months should not be capitalized.  Is this a problem with my installation? If not, where can I report the bug or pull request a change?

Comment: The package site on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-portuges) lists the current `babel` maintainer as the package maintainer. The documentation does not have more contact information (this is somewhat unusual, normally it contains an email address or a link to a bug tracking system). The website of the `babel` maintainer is http://www.texnia.com/ and it has a contact form, you could try to get in touch with him there.

Comment: @moewe, I think all the `babel` code is tracked through the main `latex2e` github repository: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e

Comment: @DavidPurton The main `babel` stuff definitely, but I don't think all language modules are even maintained by Javier. Plus he has https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish and https://github.com/jbezos/babel-english, so it seems they are decoupled from the `babel` core. But at least posting to `latex2e` would log the issue...

Comment: @moewe, you are right! `latexbug` reports that `portuges.ldf` is a third party file, not part core LaTeX.

Comment: Fred Guth, I just notice you are from Brazil. You probably want `\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice `babel` gives the output you want when using the new `ini` file system with `import=pt`.

However, it seems you are from Brazil. So maybe you could also try:

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[import=pt-BR,main]{portugues}
```

It seems that using

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=pt-PT,main]{portuguese}
```

gives uppercase months.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
% option a
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % or \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
% option b
%\usepackage{babel}
%\babelprovide[import=pt-BR,main]{portugues}
% option c
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=pt,main]{portuguese}
% end options
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Maybe we need a `nportuguese` now ...

Comment: @moewe, beats me. I am an ignorant English only speaker and the differences between german and ngerman are all a bit lost on me :)

Comment: @moewe I don't think so: `ngerman` is needed because hyphenation is different; this is not the case for Portuguese.

Comment: @egreg But how would you tell `babel` that you want the new (lowercase) month names in European Portuguese? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Language_Orthographic_Agreement_of_1990) suggests that the new orthography is different from both Euro-Portuguese and Brazilian usage in some details.

Comment: @moewe An option would be sufficient.

Comment: @egreg It might be for `babel`, but if the option is not exposed to other packages through a proper interface (ideally one whose general idea is intended to be usable for other language modules as well) then there is a risk of running into the situation we have with `polyglossia`: Options and variants are not properly accessible from the outside.

Comment: with [brazil] it worked.  But that means that [brazil] was updated to the new ortography agreement among lusophone countries and [portuguese] hasn't. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should be filed as a bug report to the maintainer of the babel-portuguese module.

In the meantime, you can fix it yourself in your documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\lowercase\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\dateportuges\expandafter{\dateportuges}%
}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

Basically, `\dateportuges` is redefined as itself, but with `\lowercase` applied.

[image]